# Sending login details to local server with a POST

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, localhost

I'm testing being able to create a user by sending a name and password to `/api/users` (returns 201):

```
const response = await request(app).post("/api/users").send(userDetails);

expect(response.status).toBe(201);
```

I'm able to test a login by that user by sending the username & password to `/api/login` (returns 200)

```
const response = await request(app).post("/api/login").send(userDetails);

expect(response.status).toBe(200);
```

I'm now trying to create a post but user needs to be signed in to do so. How do I send both the login and the POST body together?

```
const response = await request(app).get("/api/articles").send();
```

Comment: You don't, you would need to send the cookie with the session_id in order to "stay logged in". (Or the token, see comment below)

Comment: You should return a token when the user is logged in which has an expiration date. Than you can add that token as an "Authorization" header to your get request and validate the token, if the token is valid.

Comment: So when I log in I'll get a JWT back, and I send that in the header as Authorization with my POST body and it should work?

Comment: yes, passing JWT in header authorization should work

Comment: Still trying to do this. I'm using an express server and vs code and testing the endpoints in Postman.

I can log someone in using my existing, stand alone log in test. I can take the response.text from that (the JWT), put it into Bearer token authorization in Postman and POST to /api/articles but I can't figure out how to do it in VS Code/ JS/ my actual test.

At least I know the endpoint works